# Can I change the linearization of types in Scala?

Tags: scala, traits

Is there a possibility to change the linearization order of `types` specially `traits` in Scala? I can guess that it may not be a safe choice but "is it possible"?

Comment: I guess... if you are willing to put in a whole lot of effort in modifying a lot of Scala source code only to break almost all of the language... then I am sure you can.

Comment: But why do you think you need this...?

Comment: Because I am using many traits and is a headache to check which one goes first and which after, every time I have to check the code of the traits when I want to mix. Thus, I was thinking to keep their order in someway in a `field` or `method` and then even if I mix traits in a whatever order, I have to get an error mesage instead of the results of their mixings. I am thinking not to change the current linearization of scala traits but maybe to have something by my own to control (double control) their order.

Comment: If you are facing a lot of cases where you  have to consider linearization then you need to - Plan, Think and Engineer better code.

Comment: Does it mean that I cannot have something like that? Because my task is to plan with traits :)

Comment: What specific use case leads you to want to change such thing? Could you post a specific example? I believe that even if you have many traits, you can always keep things clear through self-type annotations, lazy vals and a good design.

Comment: I am saying that need of lot of linearization means bad design. Planning with traits does not mean that you have to plan with a bad architecture. Though Scala allows multiple-inheritance and gives you an elegant solution like linearization, but this does not mean that you should proceed with a bad design. Design carefully, languages can provide you with features and tools but it will always be about your design.

Comment: To put it in perspective - Thinking of changing linearization is very similar to saying that you want to eliminate gravity because the Car you built is too heavy. But again, Cars need friction ( which depends on Gravity )to move. So... Change things about your Car's design.

Comment: Yup... bad design. Advice - Use Java, which will force you to design better.

Comment: @kaktusito, how I can solve the above problem - in my edit with self-type annotations? 'Sarvesh Kumar Singh', I am understanding but I really was thinking to control easily something like in my edit up

Comment: I understand what you mean. But the only suggestable and easiest solution is to change the design.

Comment: @Sarvesh Kumar Singh, then I am going to change my design (facepalm). Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

You could write a macro annotation (with the macro paradise plugin) to do that, which would then allow you to write something like:

```
@mangleInitializationOrder class Foo extends Bar with Baz with ...
```

Of course this macro would "really" just rearrange the `extends`/`with` to ensure the correct order. And as you say, it's not a good idea in terms of readability/maintainability.

Comment: @Imm, thanks for this - I wasn't thinking that macros may offer me something. I am going to check what I can do. Thanks again